# How do I reuse HTML snippets in a django view

Tags: html, django, django-templates, components

I am working on a django project (my first), and in one of my views, I have a sophisticated html snippet with JS weaved within it. I would like to reuse this "component" somewhere else in the same view. Is there a way of achieving this? Please let me know if this design is faulty to begin with?

Comment: By "view" do you think template?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [**{% include '/my/common/template.html' %}**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) templatetag.

> Loads a template and renders it with
>   the current context. This is a way of
>   "including" other templates within a
>   template.
>
> The template name can either be a
>   variable or a hard-coded (quoted)
>   string, in either single or double
>   quotes.

Answer (score 10):

I know it's an old one but maybe someone is gonna have use of this answer.

There's also the [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags). It's like the include tag, only you can pass it arguments and process it as a seperate template.

Put this in `my_app/templatetags/my_templatetags.py`:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('my_snippet.html')
def my_snippet(url, title):
    return {'url': url, 'title': title}
```

and then my_snippet.html can be:

```
<a href="{{ url }}">{{ title }}</a>
```

then, to use this snippet in your templates:

```
{% load my_templatetags %}
{% my_snippet "/homepage/" "Homepage" %}
```

More info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if you like to reuse your HTML in different templates (rendered by different views). If so, look into [Django's template inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) mechanism:

> The most powerful -- and thus the most complex -- part of Django's template engine is **template inheritance**. Template inheritance allows you to build a base "skeleton" template that contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can override.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Django custom template tags. This way you will keep your snippets in an external file and then call them easily by something like `{{ your_custom_tag }}`. It's a very convenient method for working with reusable chunks of xhtml markup. You can even use arguments with these custom tags, something like `{{ your_custom_tag|image:"logo.png" }}`.
You can learn more about custom tags [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).